# Unable to get valid auth token for cloud foundry api

Tags: rest, cloud-foundry, pcf

I would like to use the cloud foundry api to get information about different apps running on the Pivotal Apps Manager.

When I run a GET request on https://api.[domain-to-look-into.com]/v2/apps
I keep getting this response:

```
{
    "description": "Invalid Auth Token",
    "error_code": "CF-InvalidAuthToken",
    "code": 1000
}
```

I know I need some sort of Bearer Token but I am not sure how to generate that on a front-end application like angular.  Does anyone know how to generate the Bearer Token and how to set up CRUD requests so I can get information from the cloud foundry api?

Comment: Cloud Foundry uses OAuth2, so you can use any of the OAuth2 flows to obtain a token (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/develop/docs/UAA-Tokens.md#grant-types). Using the authorization code flow is best, if it works for your app. I'm not sure that'll be best for a single page app, as it requires redirects. If you can find an OAuth2 client library for Angular, it'd be best to use that. Then you don't have to implement anything. I can't endorse this one, but it's the first that popped up on Google. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc#configuring-for-implicit-flow

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this Chrome plugin to talk to CF using Angular a while back, it's probably a good place to start. It handles authentication too.

https://github.com/danhigham/chrome-cf-client